# making calculator in python, is this approach sensible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I trying to learn to write in Python and am attempting to making a calculator. For this I am using an input to choose which type of calculation and then inputs for the numbers to be calculated.

```
print ("1. add ; 2. subtract ; 3. multiply ; 4. divide " )
print ("wat is your choise")

choise = input()


if choise    == 1  :
    num_1_1 = input()
    num_2_1 = input()
    anwsr_add = (num_1_1 + num_2_1)
print (anwsr_add)
```

and repetition for the rest of the options.

This however returns that `anwsr_add` can't be printed because it is not defined. It leads me to believe the second inputs are not valid, giving nothing equal to `anwsr_add`.

Is there a extra code for these input functions within an if stream or am I completely of track with this approach?

Comment: Hmm, mabey people misuderstand my qeustion. I'm not asking how to fix the code, just if I'm trying in the right why and or am miss using the codes.

Answer (score 1):

**This depends on what version of python you are using.**

If you are using python 3, then input() is returns a type of 'str', which leads to your error. To test this theory, try print(type(choice)) and see what type it returns. If it returns str, then there is your culprit. If not, get back to us so we can continue to debug. I've posted my approach to your problem below in python 3 just so you have a reference in case I am unable to reply. Please feel free to ignore it if you would like to write it all on your own.

```
choice = int(input('Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, 3 to multiply, 4 to divide\n'))
    if 1 <= choice <= 4:
        num1 = int(input('What is the first number? '))
        num2 = int(input('What is the second number? '))
        if choice == 1:
            answer = num1 + num2
        elif choice == 2:
            answer = num1 - num2
        elif choice == 3:
            answer = num1 * num2
        elif choice == 4:
            # In python 3, the answer here would be a float. 
            # In python2, it would be a truncated integer.
            answer = num1 / num2
    else:
        print('This is not a valid operation, goodbye')
    print('Your answer is: ', answer)
```

Comment: You can tell Python 3 is being used by the print statements (`print("text")` vs `print "text"`)

Comment: @Sagasaki Not really because print("text") works in both python 2 and 3, which is what Dalek used. So we wouldn't be able to tell just from his code syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I found is you are comparing a char data type to an int data type. When you ask for input from the user, it is stored as a character string by default. Character strings cannot be compared to integers, which is what you are trying to do with your `if` block. If you wrap the input in an `int()` call it will convert the char to an int data type, and can then be properly compared with your `== 1` statement. Additionally, within your `if` statement you call `input()` twice, and it will also give you a character string. This means if you input `1` and `1`, you will get `11` out (like `a + b = ab`). To fix this, also wrap those `input()` statements with `int()` calls. I fixed these problems in the code below:

```
choice = int(input())

if choice == 1:
    num_1_1 = int(input())
    num_2_1 = int(input())
    anwsr_add = (num_1_1 + num_2_1)
print(anwsr_add)
```

Comment: @DalekZek Glad to have helped. Please upvote those answers that have been helpful to you, and select an answer by clicking the check mark next to the vote buttons once you've found one.

Comment: Python variables are scoped to the whole function or module, not to the block. The problem isn’t that the variable is out of scope, it’s that the variable is in scope but not always assigned to.

Comment: @abarnert You're right, thanks. I got confused because indenting the print statement fixed that error, but it was just a symptom not the cause.

Comment: @abarnert Fixed my answer based on your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Hey Dalek I've copied your code and got this result:

```
1. add ; 2. subtract ; 3. multiply ; 4. divide 
What's your choise?
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Game.py", line 10, in <module>
print (anwsr_add)
NameError: name 'anwsr_add' is not defined
```

The NameError occurs because the programm trys to call `anwsr_add` while it executes the code below `if choise == ...`
You can use this code. It works. The reason why your code doesn't works is that you call `anwr_add` not in the `if choise == ...` method:

```
choise = input("1. add ; 2. subtract ; 3. multiply ; 4. divide. What's your choise?")
if str(choise) == '1':
    print('First_num:')
    num_1_1 = input()
    print('Second_num:')
    num_2_1 = input()
    anwsr_add = (int(num_1_1) + int(num_2_1))
    print (anwsr_add)
```

> > > 

Comment: It'd be a good idea to share why you made the changes you made, and explain why the `NameError` occurs.

Comment: Do you know the guy who votes up for your and mine answer?(I vote up for you)

Comment: As far as I understand it up and downvotes are anonymous.